# How to adjust the hyperparameters of MLP classifier to get more perfect performance

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning, mlp

I am just getting touch with Multi-layer Perceptron. And, I got this accuracy when classifying the DEAP data with MLP. However, I have no idea how to adjust the hyperparameters for improving the result.

Here is the detail of my code and result:

[image].

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

import numpy as np
import scipy.io
x_vals = data['all_data'][:,0:320]

y_vals_new = np.array([0 if each=='Neg'  else 1 if each =='Neu' else 2 for each in data['all_data'][:,320]])
y_vals_Arousal = np.array([3 if each=='Pas'  else 4 if each =='Neu' else 5 for each in data['all_data'][:,321]])

DEAP_x_train = x_vals[:-256]        #using 80% of whole data for training
DEAP_x_test = x_vals[-256:]         #using 20% of whole data for testing
DEAP_y_train = y_vals_new[:-256]     ##Valence
DEAP_y_test = y_vals_new[-256:]
DEAP_y_train_A = y_vals_Arousal[:-256]   ### Arousal
DEAP_y_test_A = y_vals_Arousal[-256:]

mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', activation='relu',alpha=1e-4,hidden_layer_sizes=(50,50,50), random_state=1,max_iter=11,verbose=10,learning_rate_init=.1)

mlp.fit(DEAP_x_train, DEAP_y_train)

print (mlp.score(DEAP_x_test,DEAP_y_test))
print (mlp.n_layers_)
print (mlp.n_iter_)
print (mlp.loss_)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are using SKlearn, you can use their [hyper-parameter optimization](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) tools.

For example, you can use:

- [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV)
- [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV)

If you use `GridSearchCV`, you can do the following:

1) Choose your classifier

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=100)
```

2) Define a hyper-parameter space to search. (All the values that you want to try out.)

```
parameter_space = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [(50,50,50), (50,100,50), (100,)],
    'activation': ['tanh', 'relu'],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam'],
    'alpha': [0.0001, 0.05],
    'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive'],
}
```

Note: the `max_iter=100` that you defined on the initializer is not in the grid. So, that number will be constant, while the ones in the grid will be searched.

3) Run the search:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

clf = GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
clf.fit(DEAP_x_train, DEAP_y_train)
```

Note: the parameter `n_jobs` is to define how many CPU cores from your computer to use (-1 is for all the cores available). The `cv` is the number of splits for cross-validation.

4) See the best results:

```
# Best paramete set
print('Best parameters found:\n', clf.best_params_)

# All results
means = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = clf.cv_results_['std_test_score']
for mean, std, params in zip(means, stds, clf.cv_results_['params']):
    print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r" % (mean, std * 2, params))
```

5) Now you can use the `clf` to make new predictions. For example, check the performance on your `test set`.

```
y_true, y_pred = DEAP_y_test , clf.predict(DEAP_x_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print('Results on the test set:')
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: Thanks for yr detailed comments. I really appreciate it. However, this error have occurred while running.                                                                         
  ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate  for estimator MLPClassifier.....                I have already checked this optional choices for each MLPClassifier parameter. And, it's definitely correct. Could you give me any clues about this issue?

Comment: There were some weird spaces in the keys of the `parameter_space`. If you try again, it should work!

Comment: Yes, I just found it. Finally, it works！ Thanks for yr advise!

Comment: my pleasure, any time :)

Comment: Thanks for yr kindness.I still have another question about  hidden_layer_sizes parameter.  Ex: (50,50,50) represent 3 hidden layers with 50 hidden units each,right? How about the input and output layer?  How did i initialize it via the hyperparameter?

Comment: If you check the documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), you will see `hidden_layer_sizes : tuple, length = n_layers - 2, default (100,)`. This means that you define the inners layers, but the input and output layers you don't. That means that your input layer will be the size of each item in `DEAP_x` and the output layer will have the size of the number of possible values in `DEAP_y`. The input/ouput layer size is not defined on the `__init__` but rather on the `fit`.

Comment: the explanation is quite clear！ I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to the very practical answer of @BrunoGL, I'd like to give a more theoretical answer. I'd like to suggest everyone trying to adjust hyperparameters of a simple Neural Network to read Efficient Backprop, by Lecun and others (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf). Yes it's from 1998, no it's not outdated.

It covers the impact of the main hyperparameters you have to set (activation, solver, learning rate, batches), commons traps, the problems you may encouter if you fall into them, how to spot those problems and how to solve them. A must read for everyone that want to tune a Neural Network. Plus, it's free.